# What's the closest to doing symlink functionality in S3 without having to make the s3 buckets public?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

I want to be able to send get requests from lambda to an S3 key path and have it redirect to another location if that S3 key path exists. I know that re-direct functionality exists but this requires making buckets public for static website redirects which won't work for our use case.

Is there something I can do with Route53 and/or API Gateway to simulate a symlink-like functionality?

Comment: First time I've seen a request like this. What are you doing that requires this functionality? Anyhow, there's no native support for this afaik. You could just encode this logic in your Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use for Lambda@Edge with CloudFront.

To do this, you’ll first need to deploy a CloudFront distribution with your S3 bucket as the origin. In your Lambda you should then direct the GET requests, for those objects, to your CloudFront distribution instead of the S3 bucket directly.

Once the requests are being directed to your CloudFront distribution, you’ll need a second Lambda which will be deployed at the Edge as an `Origin Response` Lambda@Edge. With this `Origin Response` Lambda@Edge you’ll intercept the response from the origin before its returned to the Viewer (ie the requester) and be able to alter the response. In the code for your Lambda@Edge you’ll be able to check if the object is being returned from the S3 origin or if the response is an error, and then build and return your redirect if necessary.

You can read more about Lambda@Edge in the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html).